# iOS reference IBOutlet from string

Tags: ios

How would i make reference to or call an IBOutlet (`UIImageView`) from a string of which is equal to the name of said IBOutlet?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image3;

NSArray nameArray = @[@"image1", @"image2", @"image3"];

//somthing that would act as below
[nameArray[0] image] = (UIImage) PredeterminedImage;
```

Comment: Use `IBOutletCollection` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html). So:

```
[self setValue:predeterminedImage forKey:nameArray[0]]
```

Objective-C is fully reflective; it knows the names of its methods at runtime and because setters have a well-known relationship to property names it can therefore set a property by string name.

This is how NIBs/XIBs/Storyboards are loaded in real life. Unlike some other platforms there's no automatic code generation, just data.

---

As to iphonic's comment that you should solve the overarching problem in a better way via `IBOutletCollection`, I think that's probably valid. The only potential gotcha is that outlet collections are unordered; the easiest fix for that is to add a custom setter that applies your sorting criteria. E.g.

```
// nobody else is going to own the array, so better make it strong
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView)
             NSArray *imageViews;

...

- (void)setImageViews:(NSArray *)imageViews
{
    _imageViews = [imageViews sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                @[[NSSortDescriptor
                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"frame.origin.y" ascending:YES]]];
}
```